# VS Code - Line in the middle of the screen

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I'm a big fan of VS Code and i'm just learning to code. But when using dart language, there is a line in the middle of my screen [the-line!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZvrc.png). I don't have this trouble in html, css or any other language. I updated my graphics cards. What do you think could be the problem?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't an issue with  your graphics card. This is a Dart setting when you install the plugin via VS Code. You should be able to modify/remove this 'line' within the settings. It appears there is a fix [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62873926/3681591). The line is simply a formatting suggestion to where you are recommended to 'break' your code or start a new line.

Answer (score 9):

Steps on getting rid of the line:

1. Go to your vs code and press on dart in the bottom of your screen
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEH82.png
2. Then click on "Configure 'dart' language based settings..." https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWMua.png
3. Find the line that says "editor.rulers": [80] and change the value to what ever you want or delete the "editor.rulers" line to get rid of that huge line on your vs code screen
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/Haass.png