# In Visual Studio Code, how do I remove the ruler line?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't seem to remove the ruler line. Is there a way to?

[image: 1]

Comment: Set this to a higher value: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62873926/8517948, that said if you want to write Dart code following [Effective Dart guidelines](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style#avoid-lines-longer-than-80-characters) you might want to keep and use that line

Answer (score 5):

Go to your `settings.json` and look for `"editor.rulers"`, removing that should remove those lines