# How to change the line length for Code wrapping in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, word-wrap

I'm trying to change the line length for Code wrapping in VSCode I've tried a lot of solutions here in Stackoverflow but it didn't work out for me, something weird.
This is an image of a dart code shows the code wrapped if it exceeded that column:

[image]

Comment: Seems like it's a duplicate of [how to change dart line length in vscode when formatting dart files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59456452/how-to-change-dart-line-length-in-vscode-when-formatting-dart-files)

Answer (score 1):

It took me long to find but finally here in Stackoverflow.
changing only editor.wordwrap in settings.json won't do it for Dart code/formatter, these setting I think is for general Vscode but should be added also:

```
{
   "editor.wordWrap": "wordWrapColumn",
   "editor.wordWrapColumn": 120,
   "editor.rulers": [120]
}
```

As for it to work for "Dart" code, these settings should be added:

```
"dart.lineLength": 120,
"[dart]": {
    "editor.rulers": [
        120
    ],
}
```

Thanks for all who answered in that question:
[Changing wordwrapping and formatting for Dart code in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59456452/how-to-change-dart-line-length-in-vscode-when-formatting-dart-files)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add these (adjust the numbers yourself) in your [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_changing-settingsjson):

```
{
    "editor.wordWrap": "wordWrapColumn",
    "editor.wordWrapColumn": 120,
    "editor.rulers": [120]
}
```

Comment: I tried it for user settings, it doesn't work for "Dart". Nothing changed.